# I need to add email/password authentication with flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have a **Google authentication** working just **fine**, and I need to create another **signUp** method (with **email/and password**), so what are the best approaches for implementing this ***signUp*** method?

I tried to create a user and it worked. But then I **can't navigate** to my other pages!

I couldn't find any good blog posts or documentation. **Note** that when the user signs up I also need to add them in firebase Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
emailPasswordLogin(BuildContext context, String email, String password)async{
  try {

    AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;



  } catch (ex) {
    print("Code: " + ex.code);
    switch (ex.code) {
      case 'ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND':
      {
        await createUser(email, password, context);
      }
      case 'ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD':
        print("wrong password);
        break;
      case 'ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL':
        print("invalid email")
        break;
      case 'ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED':
        print("Login Method not defined")
        break;
      case 'ERROR_WEAK_PASSWORD':
        print("weak password")
        break;

      default:
        print('Case ${ex.message} is not yet implemented');
    }
    return;
  }
  storeData(user, context);

}

storeData(FirebaseUser user, BuildContext context) async {
  _database = new FirebaseDatabase();

  await _database
        .reference()
        .child('user')
        .push().set(<dynamic, dynamic> async{
          "email": user.email,
         }).then((_) {
           print("Transaction commited");
           Navigator.of(context).push(
             MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextPage());
         });
}
```